# Python Dynamic programing TSP - print route

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting the final output as 80 which is the **minimum** sum of all the edges after visiting all the nodes.

I am only trying to print the full route of nodes that the program took before going back to the starting node.

somethings like this:

```
[1,2,4,3,1]
```

[image: diagram Image]

```
#This program uses dynamic programing to solve TSP problem
from sys import maxsize 
from itertools import permutations

#number of nodes
cities = 4
 
# function to implement TSP
def TSP(graph, s): 
 
    # keep all vertex other than the starting point
    vertex = [] 

    #traverse the diagram 
    for i in range(cities): 
        if i != s: 
            vertex.append(i) 
 
    # keep minimum weight
    min_path = maxsize 
    
    next_permutation = permutations(vertex)
    
    for i in next_permutation:
        # store current Path weight(cost) 
        current_pathweight = 0
        
        # compute current path weight 
        k = s 
        for j in i: 
            current_pathweight += graph[k][j] 
            k = j 
        current_pathweight += graph[k][s] 
        
        # update minimum 
        min_path = min(min_path, current_pathweight) 
    
    return min_path

# Driver Code 
if __name__ == "__main__": 
 
    # matrix representation of graph 
    graph = [[0, 10, 15, 20], 
             [10, 0, 35, 25], 
             [15, 35, 0, 30], 
             [20, 25, 30, 0]
            ] 
    s = 0

    print(TSP(graph, s))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save a `best_path` variable before iterating through the permutations and update that with the best path when you find a better path. Here is the updated code.

```
#This program uses dynamic programing to solve TSP problem
from sys import maxsize 
from itertools import permutations

#number of nodes
cities = 4
 
# function to implement TSP
def TSP(graph, s): 
 
    # keep all vertex other than the starting point
    vertex = [] 

    #traverse the diagram 
    for i in range(cities): 
        if i != s: 
            vertex.append(i) 
 
    # keep minimum weight
    min_path = maxsize 
    
    next_permutation = permutations(vertex)
    best_path = []
    
    for i in next_permutation:
        # store current Path weight(cost) 
        current_pathweight = 0
        
        # compute current path weight 
        k = s 
        
        for j in i: 
            current_pathweight += graph[k][j] 
            k = j 
        current_pathweight += graph[k][s] 
        
        # update minimum 
        if current_pathweight < min_path:
            min_path = current_pathweight
            best_path = [s]
            best_path.extend(list(i))
            best_path.append(s)
        
    
    return min_path, best_path

# Driver Code 
if __name__ == "__main__": 
 
    # matrix representation of graph 
    graph = [[0, 10, 15, 20], 
             [10, 0, 35, 25], 
             [15, 35, 0, 30], 
             [20, 25, 30, 0]
            ] 
    s = 0

    print(TSP(graph, s))
```